# Error "unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'" in Counter function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to use Counter to get the most common word in my train dataset, but I can't use with a list of lists.

This is my code:

```
from collections import Counter

#Inverse transformation of the train dataset
X_train_t=vectorizer.inverse_transform(X_train)
print (Counter(X_train_t).most_common()[-1])
```

But I get  `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`.

`X_train_t` is of type `type(X_train_t)=<class 'list'>`.

Comment: Please provide the dtype of X_train

Answer (score 0):

[inverse_transform()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.inverse_transform) returns a list of `numpy.arrays` in the form of `[array(['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'document'], dtype='<U8'), ...]`.
Join them using `numpy.concatenate()` to obtain a single array in the form of: `['this' 'is' 'the' 'first' 'document' 'this'...]`.

`Counter` sorts in descending order by default. Thus, `[0]` gives you the most frequent word.

Here as a full working example:

```
from collections import Counter

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
     'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

X_train_t=vectorizer.inverse_transform(X_train)
X_train_t= np.concatenate(X_train_t, axis=0 )
print (Counter(X_train_t).most_common()[0])
```